# MongoDB c# driver: How to serialize a list of objects as a list of object ids?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

It surprises me that i haven't found a simple answer to this question, so here it goes:

Given an object model like this -

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public List<Bar> Bars {get; set;}
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

How do I customize the mongodb c# driver to serialize a Foo instance to a document in the database that looks like this:

```
{ "Id" : "XXXXX", "Bars" : [ { "Id" : "XXXXX" }, { "Id" : "XXXXX" } ] }
```

Foos and Bars will be stored in different collections. So, I don't want to do something that will affect all Bars, because serializing a Bar to the Bar collection should keep all the properties of Bar.

I don't want any dependencies on the mongodb driver in my model classes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with referencing of separately stored objects in document DBs like Mongo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034068/how-to-deal-with-referencing-of-separately-stored-objects-in-document-dbs-like-m)

Comment: I don't consider this a dupe. My question isn't whether this is a good or bad pattern. My question is specifically whether and how I can do the mapping with settings on the Mongodb c# driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a better dupe candidate would have been [MongoDB  C# driver - serialization of POCO references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553736/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-serialization-of-poco-references?rq=1)

Anyway, to provide an answer instead getting excited over possible dupes: No, it's not possible with the C# driver to do that.

The C# driver is relatively low-level and doesn't try to be an object-document-mapper. One could probably develop an ODM based on the C# driver, because it offers a number of hooks, but, as I have pointed out in a different answer, that is an extremely challenging and large task and the result, in my opinion, is always leaky. Also, with the hooks you'd probably get a dependency on the C# driver in your code which you don't want.

Comment: I don't consider that a dupe either :) I assume you mean if I wrote a bunch of custom serializers for my top-level objects I could get this to work, but you caution against it?

Comment: Essentially yes. "A bunch of serializers" might do the trick for a very limited set of features, but complexity explodes quickly. You'd probably want transparent activation which requires quite a smart wrapper already. I consider not requiring an ORM the key reason to use NoSQL at all.